# Perl struct How to declare an array of struct within a struct

Tags: perl, struct

I have two structs

```
use Class::Struct;

struct Point =>
{
    name  => '$',
    bins => '@',
};

struct Group =>
[
    name     => '$',
    points  => '@point',
];
```

But this is not working. How can this be done? I am new to perl and have some knowledge in OOP using C# earlier.

After this, how can I access the elements? For example:

```
my $g = Group->new();
my $p = Point->new(name => "point_1", bins => ["bin_1","bin_2"],);
print $g->points[0]->name;
```

I know there are tons of mistake in my example above, but I hope it can help you guys understand what I am trying to do here. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible to combine the `@` with a class name.

The `->` after an accessor is not optional. Moreover, you should specify the index as the argument to the accessor.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature qw{ say };

use Class::Struct;

struct Point => {
    name  => '$',
    bins => '@',
};

struct Group => [
    name     => '$',
    points  => '@',
];

my $p = Point->new(name => "point_1", bins => ["bin_1","bin_2"],);
my $g = Group->new(name => 'group_1', points => [$p]);
print $g->points(0)->name;
```

Comment: Hi, lets say I have another point:
`push @{$g->points}, $p_2;` I know it works but I am confused whether this is good practice or not. Like does this push a copy into the array or just the reference? What if the object $p_2 gets destroyed?

Comment: Start a new question to ask a new question :-)

Comment: @シアジョナサン, It pushes the value of `$p_2`, which is a reference (basically a pointer). So the reference will be copied, but not the object itself. /// `$p_2` won't get destroyed as long as it's referenced (which the array does, indirectly through the reference.)